# Hide Specific Image in Gallery Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

hi every one i want to just hide href which have NO Image Src
here is my website link where i want to do this..

[Click here to see my site page](http://www.minatocars.com/stockdetails.aspx?ID=996)

i have Done this with jSFiddle but want to implement this in my website but dont figur it out why this is not working on my site

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/7cnQN/71/)

**What i am trying to do is below**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(){
        $('div#right_contan#<%=FormView1.ClientID %> div.img_slider_car p.thumbs a').each(function(index) {

            if ($('a')[index].href == 'http://localhost:37245/NewPeaceAuto - Steer_Well/WebStock_Images/noimage.png') {
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else {
                $(this).show();

            }
        });
    };
    </script>
```

here is my Source Code in asp.net

**javascript Source in Master Page**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery-1.4.2.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery.tools.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/custom.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/hoverIntent.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/menu.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

**Custom User Control Code inside page.aspx** (i am getting images in css class thumbs)

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsSTOCK">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="img_slider_car" style="width:670px;">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/Detail_Car_Img.png" />
                    <p class="CarDetail_headertext">
                        <%#Eval("make")%>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <%#Eval("model_description")%>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<%#Eval("MODEL")%></p>
                </div>
                <div class="CarDetail_Right">
                    <p style="margin-left: 8px; margin-top: 0;">
                        <a href="Negotiation.aspx?id=<%#Eval("ID")%>">
                            <input id="btnNego" value="Negotiation" type="button" class="button_3" style="width:100px"/>
                        </a><a href="EnquiryForm.aspx?id=<%#Eval("ID")%>">
                            <input id="btnEnquiry" value="Enquiry" type="button" class="button_1" />
                    </p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Chasiss: <b>
                            <%#Eval("chassis_no")%>
                        </b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Body Type:<b>
                            <%#Eval("make_category")%>
                        </b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Model Year: <b>
                            <%#Eval("MODEL")%>
                        </b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Trans: <b>
                            <%#Eval("Transmission")%>
                        </b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Color: <b>
                            <%#Eval("COLOR")%>
                        </b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Mileage: <b>
                            <%#Eval("mileage")%>
                        </b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Grade: <b>
                            <%#Eval("veh_grade")%>
                        </b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Fuel Type: <b>
                            <%#Eval("fuel_type")%>
                        </b></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <p style="padding-top:21px;" >
                    <img id="largeImg" src="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%#Eval("IMAGE1")%>" alt="Large image"  width="120px" height="90px" />
                </p>
                <p class="thumbs" style="width: 672px;">
                    <a href="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE1") %>" title="<%# Eval("make") %>  <%#Eval("model_description")%>">
                        <img src="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE1") %>" /></a> <a href="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE2") %>"
                            title="<%# Eval("make") %>  <%#Eval("model_description")%>">
                            <img src="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE2") %>" /></a> <a href="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE3") %>"
                                title="<%# Eval("make") %><%#Eval("model_description")%>">
                                <img src="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE3") %>" /></a> <a href="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE4") %>"
                                    title="<%# Eval("make") %><%#Eval("model_description")%>">
                                    <img src="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE4") %>" /></a> <a href="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE5") %>"
                                        title="<%# Eval("make") %><%#Eval("model_description")%>">
                                        <img src="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE5") %>" /></a> <a href="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE6") %>"
                                            title="<%# Eval("make") %><%#Eval("model_description")%>">
                                            <img src="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE6") %>" /></a>
                    <a href="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE7") %>" title="<%# Eval("make") %>  <%#Eval("model_description")%>">
                        <img src="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE7") %>" /></a> <a href="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE8") %>"
                            title="<%# Eval("make") %>  <%#Eval("model_description")%>">
                            <img src="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE8") %>" /></a> <a href="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE9") %>"
                                title="<%# Eval("make") %>  <%#Eval("model_description")%>">
                                <img src="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE9") %>" /></a> <a href="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE10") %>"
                                    title="<%# Eval("make") %>  <%#Eval("model_description")%>">
                                    <img src="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("IMAGE10") %>" /></a>
                </p>
            </div>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

plz suggest me the better way to do this

Comment: Can you post the code from your website?

Comment: @Suman Ray i am using Same jQuery as i wrote in JSFiddle..

Comment: It's a lot easier for us to help you if you post all the relevant code here on the question, and helps keep the site useful for others.  I can practically guarantee your personal site won't maintain this bug; how will others learn from your experience, if they can't see the issue, or if jsfiddle (a privately-run site) one day shuts down?  Because of the links, I'm downvoting your question.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein now i have updated my Question! hope you have got it now

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery three times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Selector was wrong

```
$('div#right_contan#<%=FormView1.ClientID %> div.img_slider_car p.thumbs a')
```

whenever we need to select the specific tag inside multiple id`s and class we have to be specific in this regards.. secondly for  href we can specify this as a[href$='SourceName.Extention] it will automatically garab the required content of your targeted tag

here is my solution (just need to access your targeted tag specifically)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function pageLoad() {
          $("#right_contan .img_slider_car p.thumbs a[href$='noimage.png']").hide()
      };

  </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your code to say this:

```
 $('.thumbs img').each(function(index) {    
    if (this.src == 'http://www.abumousamotors.com/WebStock_Images/noimage.png'){
        $(this).hide(); 
    } else {
        $(this).show();
    }
 });
```

It was working ok in jsfiddle because `$('img')` was the same as `$('.thumbs img')`, while I'm assuming it's not in your website.  Change it to looking at `this.src`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest too, but the OP really needs to post the actual code from the web page.  It's too hard to find what they're asking about.

Comment: Beat me to it! If you copy & paste this code into your console and run it, it will remove the images as it is supposed to. Nice work!

Comment: Also, the reason `$('img')[index]` doesn't work, is because it is grabbing from ALL the images on the page, not the ones in the selected `.each` loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree.  I've seen others just paste it in themselves, and of course I can do that if OP doesn't, but I did leave him a note hoping he'll learn how to be a good community member.

Comment: no dear still it`s not working on my site.. tell me if you want more required code sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a single line of jQuery:

```
$('.thumbs img[src$="noimage.png"]').hide();
```

BUT ... if abumousamotors.com changes their filename it won't work. So it's not really a reliable solution.

Comment: for reliability we can use something like this
$(".thumbs img[src$='noimage.png']").hide();